# How to do apt-get dist-upgrade with noninteractive?

Tags: apt, package-management, unattended-upgrades

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and using this command:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive UCF_FORCE_CONFFOLD=1 apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-package dist-upgrade
```

However I get 2 dialog prompts during this process:

[image: kdump-tools]

[image: grub-efi]

I tried searching for an answer for hours, I found pages like this but unfortunately the solutions do not prevent these dialogs: https://serverfault.com/questions/48724/100-non-interactive-debian-dist-upgrade

How would I automate selecting the first item in the case of grub-efi and selecting "yes" in the case of kdump-tools?

Comment: `--allow-downgrades` and `--allow-remove-essential` are dangerous. You're telling apt that it's okay to destroy your system if the package logic leads it that way. Human supervision of the proposed changes is strongly recommended when using those flags.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just illustrating the fact that I even tried these flags too, but ideally with a solution to the unattended problem I will then remove these flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "grub-efi grub-efi/install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1"
debconf-set-selections <<< "kdump-tools kdump-tools/install_kdump boolean true"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and explain how this helps? The OP wants to run a `dist-upgrade`, but you don't seem to be saying anything about that.

Comment: Unfortunately it still pops the dialog up, curiously, if I run sudo debconf-show kdump-tools before manually selecting it shows: "  kdump-tools/use_kdump: true" - however, after manually selecting it shows: "* kdump-tools/use_kdump: true" (the asterisk is added), any ideas?

Comment: I will accept this solution but also post my answer of what I ended up with, which is similar to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command that sets the debconf parameters looks like this:

```
echo "grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

However to make things a bit cleaner, I ended up with this Ruby code:

```ruby
debconf_rules = {
  'grub-pc' => [
    'install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1',
    'postrm_purge_boot_grub boolean false'
  ],
  'grub-efi' => 'install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1',
  'kdump-tools' => 'use_kdump boolean true',
  'postgresql-15' => 'postrm_purge_data boolean true'
}

# e.g. echo "grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1" | sudo debconf-set-selections
debconf_rules.each do |package, rules|
  rules = [rules] unless rules.is_a?(Array)
  rules.each do |rule|
    puts "Setting DPKG Rule: #{package} #{package}/#{rule}"
    `echo "#{package} #{package}/#{rule}" | sudo debconf-set-selections`
  end
end
```